# Right usage of at the earliest

Tags: phrase-usage

I read this (below) in "The Hindu":

> The aim of the National Blood Policy formulated by the government bank in 2002 was to "ensure easily accessible and adequate supply of safe and quality blood". To achieve this goal, India should look to reforming its regulatory approach **at the earliest**.

Now as per the Merriam-Webster "at the earliest means":
used to indicate the earliest possible time when something will happen or be done. In the latter sentence there is no future time specified. So, is the writer misguided?

Comment: I don't have a citation, but based on my personal experience, I believe this is idiomatic in Indian English. It is not standard in American English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why you are confused. I've seen this sentence before and I agree with you that it sounds wrong. However, it's generally understood that "at the earliest" with no future time specified simply means "as soon as possible."

Hope this helps!

Comment: "By what date can I turn in my project at the earliest", is this sentence correct then?